# Jpegcam _snap method not found

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

I've been trying to build a simple web page that simply allows the user to take their photo using their webcam, and then displays the result alongside the webcam feed. In order to achieve this I've been using the Jpegcam plugin.

However, when I run the (supposedly fully functioning) test example, I am able to get the webcam to display the input, but when I click "take snapshot" the console returns "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method '_snap' ".

The relevant html file can be found [can be found here](https://github.com/mattclements/jpegcam/blob/master/htdocs/test.html) and the javascript file [can be found here](https://github.com/mattclements/jpegcam/blob/master/htdocs/webcam.js).The plug in is pretty well documented but I'm a bit of newbie to JS so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the solution here was that this file does not work if you're running it from a file directory (e.g. C://....) It did work after a I tried running it off of the localhost on my machine using XAMPP.